# First checkbox changes it state by itself when I click on parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I can't find the reason why when I click the `Select nations` the first checkbox changes it state

In general it is a custom dropdown and when I click it opens and closes correctly but I posted version when dropdown is always open

Here is my truncated (interactive) code:

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef, StrictMode} = React;

const Checkbox = ({label}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <label className="container">
      {label}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
      />
      <span className="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  )
}

const MultiSelect = ({defaultTitle, options}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <label className="multiselect">
      <div className="wrapper open">
        <div className="selected" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
          <div className="truncated" data-value={defaultTitle}></div>
        </div>
        <div className="options">
          {options.map(option => <Checkbox key={option.id} label={option.value}/>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [nations, setNations] = useState([
    {
      "id": "ussr",
      "value": "U.S.S.R."
    },
    {
      "id": "japan",
      "value": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "id": "usa",
      "value": "U.S.A."
    },
    {
      "id": "uk",
      "value": "U.K."
    },
  ]);
  
  return <MultiSelect defaultTitle="Select nations" options={nations} />
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```css
:root {
  --padding-horizontal: 12px;
  --filter-fields-height: 35px;
  --turquoise: #1d6062;
  --filters-bg: rgba(25, 25, 28, 0.96);
}

.multiselect {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.multiselect .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.multiselect .wrapper .selected {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--filter-fields-height);
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: var(--filters-bg);
  border: 1px solid var(--turquoise);
}

.multiselect .wrapper .selected::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  right: var(--padding-horizontal);
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAAICAMAAAARDVXAAAAAElBMVEX///////9MaXH///////////9w+/2zAAAABnRSTlNAgAB/YCDRJtltAAAAMklEQVQI102KWRYAIAgCx5b7XzkT8uUHMAhDt+3Ygp+JcIFxuUCIpPilsn5knHfWqMUBMfAAtHrH0RsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.multiselect .wrapper .selected .truncated {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 90%;
}

.multiselect .wrapper .selected .truncated::before {
  content: attr(data-value);
}

.multiselect .wrapper .options {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 97%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-color: var(--filters-bg);
  border: 1px solid var(--turquoise);
}

.multiselect .wrapper.open .selected::after {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.multiselect .wrapper.open .options {
  display: flex;
}

.multiselect select {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="root" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had one label inside another label. So when I changed parent `label` tag to `div` the problem is gone